# Control de CollectionView

Tags: swift, xcode, iphone, uicollectionview

estoy desarrollando un juego para *iPhone* con `Swift 4`.
Mi problema es el siguiente: Tengo una `CollectionView` de 10 columnas y bastantes filas, más de 70, por lo que en la pantalla del *iPhone* sólo se muestran 12 filas de las más de 70)
Nos ponemos en situación:

1.- en la pantalla de *iPhone* están visibles las filas de la 5 a la 17 (por ejemplo)

2.- el jugador pulsa una de las celdas visibles (o pulsa un botón de la pantalla)

3.- Como respuesta a esa pulsación quiero que en la pantalla del *iPhone* se desplace el `CollectionView` para que sean visibles en la pantalla las filas de la 42 a la 54 (por ejemplo)

Y este es mi problema: no sé cómo hacer para que “el foco” del `CollectionView` se posicione en las filas que pretendo visualizar en pantalla.

Comment: Hola. Bienvenido a [es.so].  Te recomiendo [edit] la pregunta agregando algo de información como que has probado o que has encontrado por Internet, y sería bueno que realices el [tour] y leer [ask]. La idea es ofrecer un [mcve] en todas las preguntas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para desplazar un scrollview o un tableview, debes generar el indexpath al que te quieres desplazar y después indicárselo al collectionView o tableView.
Tu sabrás a que celda te quieres ir, y generas el indexpath con

```
let ip = IndexPath(row: xxx, section: yyy)
```

y para desplazar la collectionView

```
collectionView.scrollToItem(at: ip, at: .centerHorizontally, animated: true)
```

o para una tableView

```
tableView.scrollToRow(at: ip, at: .top, animated: true)
```

a partir de ahi puedes seguir investigando esta opcion

Comment: Perfecto, es lo que buscaba. Gracias.